# Detect if link was used to access page

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way that i can detect if a user was sent to my webpage using a link? If it uses some other language, it's fine but i would prefer HTML or JavaScript. I would like my webpage to detect if the user was sent there after clicking a link, if so then i want an if statement to return "true"

Comment: Could you explain a little better?

Comment: Link as opposed to what?

Comment: Not clear dude. Explain it better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the Referrer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer

In your javascript:

```
var myReferrer = document.referrer;
```

The referrer property is supplied by the user's browser, like the userAgent.

[Demo](http://www.things.org.uk/examples/referrerdemo.html)

The referrer value tells you the link used to access the site, so to merely detect it:

```
var hasReferrer = document.referrer != "";
```

The demo should show that now - if you follow the link above you'll get the StackOverflow id and `hasReferrer` will be true; if you click into the nav box and hit enter (i.e. direct navigation), you should get false.

`hasReferrer` here is a boolean value, so it holds either true or false. To use in an if-statement:

```
if(hasReferrer) {
   // came from a link
} else {
   // direct navigation
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it is used, i can not understand the tutorial on the site?

Comment: I want to be able to attach an if statement to it

Comment: No problem. As you seem to be new to javascript, I'll point out that MDN, the Mozilla Developer Network, is an excellent resource for javascript information.